# Select top N most frequently purchased items in each category

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm using HiveQL and I need to select the top 10 most frequently purchased items in each category. I guess the same problem can be easily solved with regular SQL..

Is there any way faster than the snippet below? I just can't understand how we can use so-called *window functions* here...

```
SELECT item, 
COUNT(item) AS freq FROM mytable WHERE category='category1' GROUP BY item ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 1
union all SELECT item, COUNT(item) AS freq FROM mytable WHERE category='category2' GROUP BY product ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 1
union all SELECT item, COUNT(item) AS freq FROM mytable WHERE category='category3' GROUP BY item ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 1
union all SELECT item, COUNT(item) AS freq FROM mytable WHERE category='category4' GROUP BY item ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 1
...
```

Table data structure:

```
item1 category1
item2 category1
item2 category1
item5 category2
item5 category2
item4 category3
item2 category4
```

Result should be:

```
item2 category1
item5 category2
item4 category3
item2 category4
```

Comment: Top 10 or top 1? Right now, with `LIMIT 1` it should get you the top 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
SELECT category, item, freq
FROM (SELECT category, item, COUNT(*) AS freq,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM mytable 
      GROUP BY category, item
     ) ci
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per category, even when there are ties for the most common.  If you want all possibilities in the case of `ties`, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Great! Thanks a ton.